# What happened to some of the symbols in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, internationalization

I was trying to make a mock-up for a video player on my browser and couldn't find the character for a speaker with three sound waves like you would normally see at the top of the screen for audio. When I went online to find the character value for it, I found this `&#x1F50A;` which renders 🔊 (what is now the Emoji speaker icon). How can I get the symbols I knew back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to reinstall the fonts Symbola or Quivira on your Lion OS.  Also you may need to specifically select these fonts for the text where you want them to display.